# Font works with LuaLaTex but not with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex

I have the following MWE. When I compile it with LuaLaTex it works fine, but when I compile it with XeLaTeX I get the error

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "GFS Artemisia" cannot be found.
```

How is that possible?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}                                       

\babelfont{rm}[Language=Default]{GFS Artemisia}
\babelfont{sf}[Language=Default]{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}[Language=Default]{FreeMono}

\begin{document}

\section{Όνομα Ενότητας}

Κείμενο.

\end{document}
```

Comment: When you select fonts by fontname, XeTeX does only find files which are installed for your operating system, while LuaTeX also finds the font if it's (only) available in the TeX Live tree.